# How to delete all files of a database in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

How to delete all files of a database in sqlite3?

I try to delete the filename I created, but there is some strange files left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html:

```
SQLite currently uses nine distinct types of temporary files:

Rollback journals
Master journals
Write-ahead Log (WAL) files
Shared-memory files
Statement journals
TEMP databases
Materializations of views and subqueries
Transient indices
Transient databases used by VACUUM
```

The following are always written in the same directory as the database file:

- rollback journal (with the same name as the database file but with the 8 characters "-journal" appended)
- WAL ("-wal" appended)
- shared-memory file ("-shm" appended)
- Master Journal File (randomized suffix)

Other temporary files can be located in the same directory, depending on a variety of factors.

See the above link for further details.

### By request

If DBNAME is a pathname of the SQLite database, you might like to consider these options for removing all the related files in the directory in which the database file lives:

```
rm -i ${DBNAME} ${DBNAME}-*
```

or:

```
rm -i ${DBNAME}*
```

or if you're quite sure, either of the above but without `-i`

Comment: Thanks for the document, I do not notice that. And you can add an example and list, so viewer can copy and paste easier.

Answer (score 4):

If you sqlite3 database filename is "/xxx/test.db", you need try to delete follow four files:

- "/xxx/test.db"
- "/xxx/test.db-shm"
- "/xxx/test.db-wal"
- "/xxx/test.db-journal"

These four files may exist, may not exist , so you should ignore the error of "file not exist" during the unlinkat/unlink syscall.